# What is the difference between scene and layer in game engine?

Tags: game-engine

What is purpose of scene and layer in game engines, and what is main difference between them. Should Scene contain many layers?

Comment: Are you talking about a specific game engine or could you narrow it down? Never heard of a general concept of "scenes and layers" in game engines.

Comment: In general the Scenes are part of game engine architecture. As far as i know some use also layers. I am building my own game engine in c++, but i am struggling with understanding of difference between those two.

Comment: What are your sources?

Comment: I do not want to be disrespectful, but there are plenty of examples in the Unity manual, or the Godot engine manual. I watch the channel on the youtube called TheCherno about game engines , made by former EA Games employee.

Comment: Thank you. It was not clear to me that you were referring to the scene graph.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - this is opinion based.

*In general, a layers classifies GameObjects.*

Imagine you have 5 cubes - `c1,c2,c3,c4,c5`, this are being rendered in your scene. And you have some behavior associated with `c3` and `c5` and they are really costly and distracting too. So, you can put them in a new layer. And tell your camera just not to render that layer.

You can put your post-processing in a different layer than camera, so only in release, they get used, instead of wasting your CPU, every time or when you don't want

You can do more with layer, it's just an example.

But that's your game-engine, you can do whatever you want.

Some links will be helpful:

- https://answers.unity.com/questions/179310/how-to-find-all-objects-in-specific-layer.html
  -